# Can't install PyQt5 with python3.9

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

I'm working on a virtual environment named 'gui' created by me with the following command.

```py
python3 -m virtualenv --python=python3.9 gui/
```

This gives me my python version as **3.9.7**

Then i'm trying to install PyQt5 in the same virtual environment using the command.

```py
pip install PyQt5
```

but this gives me a warning and the installation is unsuccessful.
The warning is the following.

```
WARNING:
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/a4/d5e4bf99dd50134c88b95e926d7b81aad2473b47fde5e3e4eac2c69a8942/PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz#sha256=2a69597e0dd11caabe75fae133feca66387819fc9bc050f547e5551bce97e5be 
(from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6).
Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/karnik/Desktop/task/task9/gui/bin/python /Users/karnik/Desktop/task/task9/gui/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/5q/fv6_j33x0qzcb2_p0d7yk8y00000gp/T/tmp5h2kuif9
Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried installing specific version but it gives me the same error.
Please help me with this.

Comment: A silly question: is virtualenv activated? like: `source gui/bin/activate` in Linux. What is your OS or environment?

Comment: Yeah it is activated and im using Mac OS Big Sur.